# how to convert a long to a much shorter string

Tags: java

Ideally, we would like to take a long(System.currentTimeMillis in java) plus a postfix long as well and convert it to a set of characters+numbers in a much shorter string.  We only want uppercase letters used.  Is there a library for this already as it would seem like a very re-usable library for generating keys that users can type in easier as they are shorter.

I guess I could always write one but it would be nice to easily just grab someone else's code/library.

example

- 0 = 0
- 1 = 1
- 2 = 2
- the rest digits
- 11 = A
- 12 = B
- 13 = C

so I can take a number and reduce the number of digits quite significantly.

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want?

Comment: "plus a postfix long" ??? plz explain

Comment: Seems like you just want a representation in base 36.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
String str = Long.toString(l, 36).toUpperCase();
```

To convert it back, use:

```
String str = "9XQ693458KF";
long = Long.parseLong(str, 36); // No need to use toLowerCase here
```

The 36 refers to the radix (10 digits + 26 characters).

JavaDoc references:

- [`Long.toString(long, int);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString%28long,%20int%29)
- [`Long.parseLong(String, int);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: @Bohemian - That's [MAX_RADIX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX). The code would be better to use `Character.MAX_RADIX` instead of hard-wired `36`.

Comment: @TedHopp But 36 corresponds exactly to the requirements as stated by OP, whether or not it is `MAX_RADIX`.

Comment: @ted yeah just looked that up :/

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Since when are letters restricted to ASCII alphabetic characters?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Okay. I missed the part about "easily type"

Comment: Not sure you need to convert to lower case to convert back.  The parse is not case sensitive which why you have only base 36 and not 36+26.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is perhaps to convert the numbers to base-36:

```
Integer.toString(n, 36).toUpperCase()
Long.toString(n, 36).toUpperCase()
```

This will use digits from `0` to `9` and uppercase letters from `A` to `Z`.

Comment: Better to use `Character.MAX_RADIX` instead of `36`. It's the same value, but it makes the code clearer.